# Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. getAllData @ Kode.gs:26

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i got error :
Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.
getAllData  @ Kode.gs:26

At my script :

```
function getAllData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var firebaseUrl = "my link";

  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);

  var dataSet = [base.getData()];
  

  // the following lines will depend on the structure of your data
  var rows = [],
      data;

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    for (j = 0; j < dataSet[i].length; j++) {
      //check your data tye in firebase and update accordingly 
      //for eg : my data types are id,name,batch 
    rows.push([data[j].id,data[j].name,data[j].batch]);
    }
  }

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1, rows.length,3 );
  dataRange.setValues(rows); 

}
```

i try to export my database form Firebase realtimedatabase that have 5 variabels

i try to solved it and it can be export my database to spreadsheets

Comment: I would check `rows` before you `setValues`.  I suspect its empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(rows && rows.length > 0) {
   dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1, rows.length,3 );
   dataRange.setValues(rows); 
}
```